# ¿Cómo comprobar si un número es pandigital?

Tags: python

Muy buenas, para un proyecto tengo que desarrollar una función que indique, despues de evaluar un número, si éste es pandigital. Es decir que contenga al menos una vez, los números de 0 a 9.

Estoy haciendo formación a distancia, sin tutor, ni compañeros a los cuales consultar, y así se me está haciendo un poco cuesta arriba.

He probado hacerlo empleando los ciclos while y for anidados y sin anidar, usando condicionales porque debe devolver un boolean, tirando de métodos, paso de pensar que mejor cadenas que listas y tuplas y viceversa, etc. Siempre me encuentro con un escollo que no consigo, desde mis escasos conocimientos, contestar.

Mi última apuesta ha sido:

Declarar los números a comprobar dentro de una lista.

Con un ciclo "for x in lista" intentar comprobar si los elementos de la lista se encuentran dentro de la cadena. La cadena en este caso la aporta un usuario, proviene de un input. Al final el resultado es que el programa imprima "Su número es (o no) pandigital".

La pregunta es: ¿se puede hacer esto, que la variable del "for" sea un elemento de la lista previamente declarada y compruebe si este elemento se encuentra en la cadena que ingresa el usuario?. Por lo que he podido leer pareciera que es al revés, se busca si una cadena se encuentra dentro de la lista/tupla.

Gracias por vuestra orientación,
Nailette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturalmente que puedes hacer lo que has planteado.

Si no entendí mal, tienes una lista de dígitos, que sería por ejemplo:

```
digitos = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

y pretendes iterar por esta lista y ver si cada uno de ellos está en la cadena dada, que digamos que es la variable `entrada`. Sería así:

```
pandigital = True
for digito in digitos:
    if digito not in entrada:
       pandigital = False
```

Como ves, partimos de la hipótesis de que sí es pandigital, y por eso comienzo haciendo `True` esa variable. Seguidamente itero por la lista de dígitos y tan pronto como encuentre uno que no está en la entrada dada, ya sé que entonces no es pandigital, por lo que pongo esa variable a `False` (y podría haber añadido también un `break` para salir del bucle, pues no hace falta seguir mirando más digitos).

Al terminar el bucle, si la variable `pandigital` aún es `True`, es que todos han sido encontrados.

Detalles:

- La lista de dígitos no necesita ser una lista. Podría ser igualmente una cadena así:

  ```
  digitos = "0123456789"
  ```

  pues cuando hagas `for digito in digitos` igualmente irás obteniendo uno a uno los caracteres de esa cadena.
- Es más, no necesitas crear a mano esa cadena, pues el módulo `string` tiene una variable llamada `digits` que ya tiene ese valor, con lo que simplemente puedes hacer:

  ```
  import string

  pandigital = True
  for digito in string.digits:
      if digito not in entrada:
         pandigital = False
  ```

### Bonus

Sin bucles ni nada, podrías convertir la cadena de entrada en un conjunto, usando `set(entrada)`. Ese conjunto contendrá como elementos los caracteres de esa entrada, sin repetirse. Basta que lo compares con el conjunto de los dígitos. Si son iguales, es pandigital. Entonces:

```
if set(entrada) == set(string.digits):
   pandigital = True
else:
   pandigital = False
```

Es más, ya que el resultado de la comparación tras el `if` es un booleano, puedes asignárselo directamente a la variable `pandigital`, y te ahorras así el `if/else`. Es decir:

```
pandigital = set(entrada) == set(string.digits)
```

Python tiene unos tipos de datos muy potentes, y conocerlos ayuda a simplificar el código y evitar bucles en muchas ocasiones.

Comment: Hola @abulafia vote a favor de la respuesta que brindaste, una consulta si en el bucle `for` dentro del condicional `if` se empleara un `break` o `return` toda vez que el menor número [pandigital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandigital_number) en base `10` es `1023456789`, *-si uno ingresa digamos `210` bastaría que no tenga el tres para que se corte la iteración*- podría medirse la diferencia de rendimiento con `set`... no he hecho las pruebas pero supongo que con `import timeit` se podría verificar.

Comment: @HubertRonald No entiendo tu consulta. La posibilidad de salir del bucle con un `break` ya la mencioné en la respuesta. ¿Quieres decir que quizás con esa "optimización" el bucle pudiera ser más veloz que el método de los conjuntos? Es una idea interesante. Para verificarlo habría que medir tiempos con muchos números generados al azar, pues según el número el bucle acabaría antes o después, mientras que en el caso del conjunto el tiempo no dependerá de eso

Comment: En efecto @abulafia, a lo que iba para ser más exacto, si se mira el `número pandigital` que se emplea en wikipedia `1223334444555556666667777777888888889999999990` creo que se podrían remover los elementos repetidos (`210210`) antes de que entren al `bucle` (con su `break` incluido claro) o al `set`, no sé si dividir el procedimiento conlleve a ganar rendimiento. [Python: Best Way to remove duplicate character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799036/python-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-character-from-string)

Comment: Versus una vez removidos todos los números repetidos y ordenados, sólo bastaría verificar `'0123456789'==digitos` quizás esto es algo similar a lo que hace el `set`, *-la verdad sólo estoy especulando-* porque no sé cómo ha sido implementada dicha función (`set`) de forma interna en **Python**.

Comment: Ok ya lo encontré @abulafia [Internal working of Set in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-set-in-python/) *-Funcionamiento interno de la Función Set en Python-* mencionan que en el escenario menos favorable el tiempo de computo es O(n) para la función **Set** y como en este caso se trata de una intersección de cadenas (en realidad si una está incluida en la otra), se toma la de menor longitud (entrada o dígitos) en tal sentido, el costo computacional como máximo sería **O(10)** o en función a la base que se trabaje el número pandigital.

Answer (score 2):

El uso de `sets` en python es muy eficiente, tal como se emplea en la solución de @abulafia. Puede que una solución más *"semántica"* con respecto a lo que significa **pandigital** podría ser ésta:

```
pandigital = all(digito in entrada
                 for digito in string.digits)
```

Que en texto claro sería: *"todos y cada uno de los dígitos están en la `entrada`"*.

Comment: Hola @ChemaCortes, buen punto el que acotas... investigando incluso un poco más, como el número de elementos coincide con la `base`, se puede emplear una función anónima para generalizar la pregunta a cualquier `base`, dentro del rango `1` al `10`: `pandigital = lambda entrada, base: len(set(entrada))==base`.

Comment: @HubertRonald Acabo de ver tu comentario (después de un año). No funcionaría bien. Por ejemplo: `pandigital("1", base=2)` ó `pandigital("13", base=2)`

Comment: La idea @ChemaCortes era en ese momento examinar la longitud de dígitos antes de aplicar el filtro respectivo (con el "set" o "for") ya que siempre la longitud de un pandigital va a coincidir con su base (de uno a diez) tal como lo leí en este enlace de wikipedia [Pandigital Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandigital_number) pues sólo restaría permutar esos números pequeños para obtener todos los pandigitales respectivos de dicha base (aunque eso escapa a la pregunta del OP). A eso me refería con chequear la base, nada más.

Answer (score 0):

Muy agradecida **@abulafia** y **@ChemaCortes** por vuestra ayuda. Voy a leer las sugerencias detenidamente para comprenderlas y ver cual sería la más acorde utilizar según mi nivel en el curso, que veo algunas opciones "avanzadas" ;-). Pero me dejáis perpleja de cuantos caminos podrían llevar a Roma como dice el dicho. Python no deja de sorprenderme y eso que apenas acabo de empezar!!.